# How can i drag formula from left to right?

Tags: excel

I have the following table. I want to fill in the empty cell by using this formula: `=SUM(M2:N2)`. When I drag this formula from left to right (`col 0` to `2`...), it becomes `=SUM(N2:O2)`. I want it to become `=SUM(M3:N3)` not `=SUM(N2:O2)` how can I do this?

```
ENG Date    0   1   2   3   4   5   6

Z#1 6/1                         
Z#1 6/2                         
Z#1 6/3                         
Z#1 6/4
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) and pick the row to SUM by referencing the relative column.

```
=SUM(INDEX($M:$N, COLUMN(B:B), ))
```

[image: Drag SUM ROWS right]

Resist the urge to use the volatile [OFFSET function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592).

Comment: Thanks, so what is B:B in COLLUMN , why is B:B?