# How to change increment when you drag down the formula?

Tags: excel, formula, increment

I have the following formula:

```
=SUM(INDEX($M50:$N72,COLUMN(B:B),))
```

When I drag the formula down, it becomes:

```
=SUM(INDEX($M51:$N73,COLUMN(B:B),))
```

As you can see the cell increment is by 1.

### Question

How can I change increment by other number like, `24`, for instance? So that when I drag down the formula should become:

```
=SUM(INDEX($M74:$N96,COLUMN(B:B),))
```

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66

Comment: Sample data would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This appears what you are asking for (it takes the current row of a formula, multiplies one row less by 24 [assuming you start on row 1 and copy down], and adds in the starting row numbers), although I doubt it does what you want. Are you sure you want the row number of the index function to be "COLUMN(B:B)"?

```
=SUM(INDEX(INDIRECT("$M"&(ROW()-1)*24+50&":$N"&(ROW()-1)*24+72),COLUMN(B:B)))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's preferable to avoid the volatile `INDIRECT` in such situations, if possible. What's more, `ROWS` is a much better choice than `ROW` (especially in its unqualified form, i.e. `ROW()`) here, viz:

`=SUM(INDEX($M:$N,50+24*(ROWS($1:1)-1)+1,))`

which is equivalent to:

`=SUM($M51:$N51)`

and, when copied down, to:

`=SUM($M75:$N75)`

`=SUM($M99:$N99)`

etc., etc.

I confess I have no idea why you are using a construction such as `COLUMN(B:B)` for `INDEX`'s *row_num* parameter.

If you're interested in an explanation as to my statement regarding `ROW` vs `ROWS`:

http://excelxor.com/2014/08/25/row-vs-rows-for-consecutive-integer-generation/

Regards

Comment: re: *"I confess I have no idea..."* - You would have to go back to the OP's previous question at [How can i drag formula from left to right?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32831880/how-can-i-drag-formula-from-left-to-right).

Comment: Ah, I see. Many thanks. Personally I think COLUMNS is a slightly more rigorous choice (e.g. COLUMNS($B:C) in place of your COLUMN(B:B)) since column insertions within the range may lead to erroneous results with COLUMN, unlike with COLUMNS.

Comment: I used to use `ROWS($1:1)` and `COLUMNS($A:A)` but I discovered that `ROW(1:1)` is faster. It takes several thousand rows to make an appreciable difference but I found this out when filling down a formula to 500K rows.

Comment: Really? That is very interesting indeed. If that's the case, and users are made aware of the dangers of row/column insertions to which these constructions are vulnerable, then it may well be that it's a worthwhile offset. Do you have any results that show just how much faster ROW/COLUMN can be than ROWS/COLUMNS?

Comment: By themselves, `ROW(1:1)` vs `ROWS($1:1)` is only a few milli-seconds faster over several thousand rows but it seems to make more of a difference when used as part of a larger formula. Don't have stats on the latter at the moment and the former can be proven with a few lines of code ; just relating personal experience.